# Return distinct from sql statment odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have total 3 row in database and one row where is ID = 1, in console display 3 row instead one!

```
@api.multi 
    def call_func(self):
        result = []
        for data in self.search([]):
            self._cr.execute('''select distinct
                    date
                from
                    mytable
                 WHERE id = 1''')
            for line in self._cr.dictfetchall():
                print line["date"]
```

I'm add distinct but not work.

Output is:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00
2016-01-01 00:00:00
```

I need 2016-01-01 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL statement looks good. Did you execute that statement on the DB server directly using a client? Did you get only one record?

If yes, I think your problem might lie in `self.search([])`. Is that a function you wrote? does that perform a search on the records? If so, is it possible you are searching based on an empty string and this returns all 3 records of your table?

If self.search([]) returns an array of 3 elements then you are simply doing `SELECT distinct` on the same row three times.

If that's your problem, then you may fix it by removing this part:

```
for data in self.search([]):
```

Comment: Exactly, this last hint is the problem here. With 3 rows in database, search will return a `RecordSet` with 3 entries. So the query will (for each) be excuted 3 times, which will output 3 times the same line.